# How to plot the lines first and points last

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple plot with several sets of points and lines connecting each set.  I want the points to be plotted on top of the lines (so that the line doesn't show inside the point).  Regardless of order of the `plot` and `scatter` calls, this plot comes out the same, and not as I'd like.  Is there a simple way to do it?

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def poisson(m):
    def f(k):
        e = math.e**(-m)
        f = math.factorial(k)
        g = m**k
        return g*e/f
    return f

R = range(20)
L = list()
means = (1,4,10)
for m in means:
    f = poisson(m)
    L.append([f(k) for k in R])
colors = ['r','b','purple']

for c,P in zip(colors,L):
    plt.plot(R,P,color='0.2',lw=1.5)
    plt.scatter(R,P,s=150,color=c)

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(-0.5,20)
ax.set_ylim(-0.01,0.4)
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You need to set the Z-order.

```
plt.plot(R,P,color='0.2',lw=1.5, zorder=1)
plt.scatter(R,P,s=150,color=c, zorder=2)
```

Check out this example.
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html

Comment: I love zorder, allows for such fun graphs on my reports I often spend more time making them look fancy than on the actual content /slapselfonwrist

Comment: @arynaq I'm curious. How is just the order of plotting allow for such fun? :)