# Plot is obscuring other plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have one scatter plot and one line plot in the same figure. I create it using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = plt.scatter([0], [0], color = 'r')
line, = ax.plot(pos_data.x, pos_data.y, color = "k")
```

The line plot is currently obscuring the scatter plot, but I would like it the other way around (i.e. it should look like the line plot is being rendered first, and the scatter plot on top of that one).

Is this possible?

Comment: What happens if you reverse the order of the scatter and line plots?

Comment: @briansrls Tried without success :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the Z order

```
 plt.plot(x, y, 'r', zorder=1, lw=3)
 plt.scatter(x, y, s=120, zorder=2)
```

> The default drawing order for axes is patches, lines, text.  This order is determined by the zorder attribute.  The following defaults
>   are set
>
> ```
>       Artist                        Z-order               
>       Patch / PatchCollection      1
>       Line2D / LineCollection      2 
>       Text                         3
> ```
>
> You can change the order for individual artists by setting the zorder.
>   Any individual plot() call can set a value for the zorder of that
>   particular item.

Comment: It works like a charm! Please amend your answer with the necessary code instead of the link (i.e. `plt.scatter(..., zorder = 10)`) as it can become obsolete, and I'll gladly accept the answer as well.

Comment: @pingul that's a good point, I just did

Answer (score 1):

**Duplicate question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314379/how-to-plot-the-lines-first-and-points-last-in-matplotlib).**

You need to set the `zorder` for each graph, larger values stay on top:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Data:
    pass

pos_data = Data()
pos_data.x = [1,2,3,4,5]
pos_data.y = [7,2,5,3,4]

fig  = plt.figure()
ax   = fig.add_subplot(111)
scat = ax.scatter(pos_data.x, pos_data.y, color = 'r', zorder=2)
line = ax.plot(pos_data.x, pos_data.y, color = "k", zorder=1)
```

You can also achieve the same thing by setting a marker and its colour on your plot (see [`matplotlib.plot` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) for more options):

```
...
line_with_markers = ax.plot(pos_data.x, pos_data.y, color = "k",
                            marker='o', markerfacecolor='red')
```